# tradução de "you call the game plan"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Eu estou lendo uma HQ americana. Aqui está o contexto.

O Homem-Aranha está fugindo, juntamente com um novato, de uma situação muito perigosa. O rapaz pergunta para onde eles devem ir e o herói responde "Just not here!". O outro personagem faz o seguinte comentário: "You're the "pro" ... you call the game plan."

Pelo que entendi, o novato está dizendo que vai deixar para o Homem-Aranha decidir o que fazer e simplesmente vai seguir os seus planos. Alguém teria uma ideia de como dizer isto, em português, sem sacrificar muito a expressão original?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Tu decides a **estratégia***  ou *decide tu a **estratégia*** é uma opção possível. A tradução mais literal é **plano de jogo**, que também se usa em português, se bem que é mais frequente ser usada em sentido literal:

> O **plano de jogo** foi perfeito: fechar muito bem no meio, não os deixar passar e contra-ataque sempre pelo lado esquerdo.

Também se encontram usos não literais, como na frase em inglês que dás:

> No papel, o **plano de jogo** é ambicioso, particularmente para quem acaba de completar o seu primeiro trabalho de produção com «Nell», uma co-produção com a Fox, a detentora original do guião.

Os exemplos são do [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/).

Comment: I like "estratégia".  Good call. +!

Comment: estratégia do jogo